# setting sbt scalafx project

Tags: scala, javafx-2, sbt

javafx is now in oracle-jdk.

scalafx gives delicious examples in its repository

The main questions I'm not being able to answer is "How to get started with scalafx"?

How can I add scalafx libary dependencies on my sbt project?

Comment: did you try this? http://www.xenonique.co.uk/blog/?p=516

Comment: @KimStebel: it is some kind of video not a programmer documentation.

Comment: it should be a screen cast about how to set up a scalafx project with sbt...

Comment: there is no way to a screencast for replacing normal documentation. I  recognize high screencast usability for graphical designers and so on. But using video to show piece of code is something very ugly to me.

Comment: where did I say that it's a good idea? it's better than nothing though

Comment: So much ingratitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it the following way: I cloned the scalafx repository, build the jar using `sbt package`, then just copied the resulting jar into `lib/` directory of my project. Make sure to reference your ${JAVAFX_HOME}/lib/jfxrt.jar as well.

If you want to use local maven, just run `sbt publish-local` in your scalafx dir, then add the following dependency to your project:

```
"org.scalafx" % "scalafx" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

(Look up that version in scalafx build.sbt, I pasted what was in mine)

Comment: I intended to do so. I'm hoping there is more clear way to set sbt

Comment: @ayvango - As far as I know, they do not publish their package on Maven, thus there is no better way :)

Comment: I may use scalafx sbt for exporting build artifact to my local maven. It seems more technology advanced

Comment: one more thing: your should replace "ScalaFX" with "scalafx" if you want sbt to find it in local storage

Answer (score 4):

ScalaFX is soon to reach a stable release state.
As I write this you can find the published artifacts for version 1.0.0-M2 on the [maven central repo](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cscalafx)

Adding the dependency to your sbt build should suffice

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "1.0.0-M2"
```

Comment: They've published 1.0.0-M3

Comment: 1.0.0-M6 seems to be the latest

Answer (score 0):

@ayvango i have created a giter8 scalafx project template.just use

```
  g8 jugchennai/scalafx.g8
```

You just need a new version of JDK, Giter8 and SBT. Dependency settings for javafx, scala, scalafx are predefined! IDE support also available.

URL : https://github.com/jugchennai/scalafx.g8

Comment: so, the developers have accomplished scalafx mavenization finally, haven't they?